# Resolve foreign keys to data models with Angular HttpClient and Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

Suppose I have a mother and child entity. The mother has a foreign key with the child's ID. However, the API can only access all mothers and children from different endpoints (not single ones). The result is allways a full list of mothers and potentials children. *Now I want to resolve this foreign key on the application side.* At best with a transformer.

I am absolutely unsure, if this way is the right one. My favorite solution would be to avoid `child: Observable<Child>` inside of `class Mother`. `child: Child` would be the best solution.

**models.ts**

```
/**
 * Entities coming from API
 */
export class ApiMother {
  id: number;
  child: number;
}

export class ApiChild {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

/**
 * Entities used in application
 */
export class Mother {
  id: number;
  child: Observable<Child>
}

export class Child {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**mother.service.ts**

```
export class MotherService extends BaseApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private transformer: MotherTransformerService,
  ) {
    super(auth);
  }

  /**
   *  Return list of mothers.
   *
   * @return An `Observable` of `Mother` for the request, with a response body in JSON.
   */
  public getAll(): Observable<Mother[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<ApiMother[]>(this.url)
      .pipe(map(
        obj => this.transformer.fromApiModel(obj))
      );
  }
}
```

**mother-transformer.service.ts**

```
export class MotherTransformerService {

  constructor(
    private childService: ChildService
  ) {
  }

  /**
   * Mutate `Mother` to fit application needs.
   *
   * @param apiModel: ApiMother
   * @return Mother
   */
  fromApiModel(apiModel: ApiMother): Mother {
    let model = new Mother;

    const child: Observable<Child> = this.childService.findOne(apiModel.child);

    model = {
      id: apiModel.id,
      child,
    };

    return model;
  }
}
```

**child.service.ts**

```
export class childService extends BaseApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private transformer: ChildTransformService, // Concatinates `lastName` and `firstName` to `name`.
  ) {
    super(auth);
  }

  /**
   * Return list of children.
   *
   * @return An `Observable` of `Child[]` for the request, with a response body in JSON.
   */
  public getAll(): Observable<Child[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<ApiChild[]>(this.url, this.options)
      .pipe(map(
        list => list.map(obj => this.transformer.fromApiModel(obj)))
      );
  }

  /**
   * Return one single `Child` correlating with specified ID.
   *
   * @param id: ID of `Child`
   * @return An `Observable` of `Child`
   */
  public findOne(id: number): Observable<Child> {
    return this.getAll()
      .pipe(
        filter((child: Child) => child.id === id)[0]
      );
  }
}
```

I am happy about any help or recommendation. Most probably this thread is a duplicate of another, but I could not find any correlating question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I would change how you are getting the child. Right now, each time you want 1 child, you are getting the full list from the server again, then filtering it.  You may as well just get them all in one go, and store them as a variable in the service so they can be accessed again later, or have a proper method to get a single child from the server on demand if the data might get stale.

You can choose to sort that out in the future, but keeping your current code as is, changing the mother transform to return an observable would help.

```js
export class MotherTransformerService {

  constructor(
    private childService: ChildService
  ) {
  }

  /**
   * Mutate `Mother` to fit application needs.
   *
   * @param apiModel: ApiMother
   * @return Mother
   */
  fromApiModel(apiModel: ApiMother): Observable<Mother> {
    let model = new Mother;

    const child: Observable<Child> = this.childService.findOne(apiModel.child);

    
    return child.pipe(map(c => {
       model = {
         id: apiModel.id,
         child: c,
        };

        return model;

    });
  }
}
```

Now that fromApiModel for mother is an Observable, we will use switchMap instead of map

```js
export class MotherService extends BaseApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private transformer: MotherTransformerService,
  ) {
    super(auth);
  }

  /**
   *  Return list of mothers.
   *
   * @return An `Observable` of `Mother` for the request, with a response body in JSON.
   */
  public getAll(): Observable<Mother[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<ApiMother[]>(this.url)
      .pipe(switchMap(
        obj => this.transformer.fromApiModel(obj))
      );
  }
}
```

Now we have `Mother.child: Child` instead of `Mother.child: Observable<Child>`.

There may be some import issues or slight syntax issues since this isn't in a stack blitz to check, but based on your current code I think you could probably figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for the your recommendation. I will test it soon. You are absolutely right, I does not make any sense to fetch the whole list everytime. Caching is planned client-site. This is WIP and I have to brigde the time till the API has this functionality.